# How to render HTML in python?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

**This code does not work for me**

I would like to know a way to render html using python **without** tkinterhtml

When loading `google.com`, I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python scripts\project\file.py", line 10, in search
    html = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 10955: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\python scripts\project\file.py", line 12, in search
    html = htmlBytes.decode("utf16")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x3e in position 14624: truncated data
```

I am working on this for a project and am launching the code using the `import` keyword. My code doesn't work and closes the window after the search funtion finishes.

```
import urllib.request
import tkinter
from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame

def search():
    url = urlInput.get()
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    htmlBytes = page.read()
    try:
        html = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")
    except:
        html = htmlBytes.decode("utf16")
    frame.set_content(html)

    page.close()

screen = tkinter.Tk()
screen.geometry("700x700")
frame = HtmlFrame(screen, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
urlInput = tkinter.Entry(screen)
urlInput.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=10,rowspan=4,sticky="news")
searchBtn = tkinter.Button(screen,text="search",command=search)
searchBtn.grid(row=0,column=11,sticky="news")
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by using the `tkinterweb` library.

Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinterweb import HtmlFrame

screen = tkinter.Tk()
screen.geometry("700x700")
frame = HtmlFrame(screen, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
urlInput = tkinter.Entry(screen)

def search():
    frame.load_website(urlInput.get())

button = tkinter.Button(screen,text="search",command=search)
frame = HtmlFrame(screen)
urlInput.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
button.grid(row=1,column=0)
frame.grid(row=2,column=0)
screen.mainloop()
```

This is for anyone who wants to know how I solved it

Comment: Note: this library cannot process javascript and much of css. I recommend using QtWebEngine as an alternative library for PyQt5

Answer (score 3):

tkinter does not have the ability to render HTML. You'll have to use a third-party library. Since you explicitly said you don't want to use tkinterhtml you'll have to find some other third-party renderer.

Comment: @aanginer I only add link to example module [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) which allows to use Chromium in different GUIs and there is example for [tkinter](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/tkinter_.py)

Answer (score 1):

You're decoding the `google.com` page as `'utf8'` or `'utf16'`; however, the `google.com` page uses the ISO-8859-1 encoding:

The header returned by `google.com` is:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

You will need to decode the page using `'ISO-8859-1'` to avoid the "codec can't decode byte 0x.." errors.

Answer (score -2):

Flask has a tool called render template, I use it for my website and it's not hard to implement either.... here is an example:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask import render_template

    app = Flask(__name__)
    #sets app route and renders file
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
      return render_template('index.html')
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port="any port number here", debug=True)
    #debug just refreshes the main file (app.py or something.py) when a change is made
```

I suggest you also check out the docs on Flask to get a full understanding of it, I really hope this answers your question
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/

Comment: I know about flask. In fact, I've actually written a website in flask. I need To render it in a window and not on localhost.